# someone could explain to me why this command apdu?

Tags: smartcard

```
00 B0 82 00 00 11 46 22
```

The read binary command is usually written like this:

```
B0 00 00 00 00
```

I could explain the last 2 bytes?
I do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

The command is syntactically wrong: Read Binary (with even INS code) being a case 2 command (no command data, response expected) '00 11 46' would encode an extended LE of 0x1146. The trailing '22' makes the APDU invalid.

By all means try to get hands on a ISO 7816-4 copy and make yourself familiar with it.

Comment: I obtained the command of a snifing a program that works very well